# Question about performance when doing math in c

Tags: c, performance, math, optimization

Code X:

```
float result;
int a, b;

result = (float)a + (float)b;
```

Code Y:

```
float result, a, b;

result = a + b;
```

Which code is the fastest and uses less resources?

Comment: The difference is tiny enough so you can ignore it.

Comment: These two codes do different things. Both have undefined behaviour though as the variables are unintialized.

Comment: This question is meaningless without context. In either case, `a` or `b` must have been given some values previously. So there is prior code that, in one case, works with `int` to produce `int` values for `a` and `b` and, in the other case, works with `float` to produce `float` values for `a` and `b`. Therefore, the difference between two programs that use Code X or Code Y is in more than just Code X or Code Y, and so the time difference in their executions is not just due to Code X or Code Y. Answering which is faster must depend on other parts of the program too.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Showing declarations before other code is a common convention for showing the types of variables and does not mean the code in a program literally contains just those declarations immediately followed by the other code shown. You should know that by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no overflows, Y will be very slightly faster because there is an overhead of converting an `int` to a `float`.

However the difference will be very small and unless performance is critical good practice is to represent `a` and `b` by the most 'natural' data type rather than most performant. That is unless they have a fractional part (by nature) `float` is unsuitable even if some calculations have `float` results.

Also notice that the range `float` can represent exact whole numbers is likely narrower than `int`. On a typical platform where `int` is 32-bit and `float` also 32-bit but uses some bits to encode the exponent.

On some platforms `double` may be faster still because `float` is internally converted to `double` and back.
Unless space is critical (e.g. many millions of values on hosted environments or a tiny embedded device) `double` is normally recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You are using uninitialized variables, and the two pieces of code are not exactly the same due to the precision loss, but I will ignore that, lets talk conceptually.

I assume in both cases 'a' and 'b' are integer values, regardless of their type.

First, when talking about floating point operations, it is always architecture dependent. Not any processor support floating point operations in the same way.

However OK, lets assume you are talking about x86_64.

Next, there is optimization. Pay attention that `(float)a + (float)b` is not the same as `(float)(a + b)`, because floating point conversion may lose precision (although for int maybe not, for long definitely you can lose precision). So this **cannot** be optimized or cannot be optimized at least in some cases.

So optimizer will probably not make much difference between the two cases.

Now, also pay attention that the conversion from int to float and back is a separate assembly instruction (unlike from int to long for example) because integers and floating numbers have different in-mem format, this is `cvtsi2ss` instruction.

**Conclusion:**
The first case does the same amount of calculations, but it also has conversions. So it is *very slightly slower*.

See the disassemble here that illustrates the difference:

Case 1: https://godbolt.org/z/fsMjoE

Case 2: https://godbolt.org/z/v1xzr1

Comment: `Pay attention that (float)a + (float)b is not the same as (float)(a + b), because floating point conversion may lose precision` problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Those two examples are completely different and comparing them makes a very little sense.  Why?

The fist exmaple adds two integers converted to floats. The compiler has to convert both to float and then to add them.

The second example just adds two floats without any conversion.

I believe that you want to compare

```
float foo(int a, int b) {
    return (float)a + (float)b;
}

float bar(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xvaarY

```
The resulting code 
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        pxor    xmm1, xmm1
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, edi
        cvtsi2ss        xmm1, esi
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
bar:
        add     edi, esi
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, edi
        ret
```

Function bar is more efficient but it may not produce the same result if the addition of two integers overflow (they are added first, then the result is converted to the float) which invokes the UB.

Answer (score -1):

This C code:

```
float test(int a, int b)
{
  float result = (float)a + (float)b;
  return result;
}

float test1(float a, float b)
{
  float result = a + b;
  return result;
}
```

Might get compiled into something like this with an optimizing compiler:

```
test:
        cvtsi2ss        xmm1, edi
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, esi
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
test1:
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
```

So you can see that `test1` does less than `test`, which is normal because both functions don't do the same thing. In `test1` everything is `float` so no conversions need to be done. In `test` the `int`s need to be converted to float before the addition is done.